# how to do unit-test on compiled template when using "controller as"?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I try to unit-test my controller with template. I can test it if everything ties to $scope. However, once I use "controller as" syntax, it doesn't work. That make sense because now everything ties to controller. But how to make it work then ?

I use Jasmine with Karma as my test environment.

Comment: lets say you have `vm` as the controllerAs name. then you can use $scope.vm to get access to the model

Comment: Thanks ! That's a way to do it, but it sounds a bit hacky. Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 2):

lets say you have `vm` as the controllerAs name. then you can use `$scope.vm` to get access to the model

Comment: I found a way but not sure if it is the best tho.

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out.

```
Ctrl = $controller('Ctrl as vm', { $scope: $scope });
```

Comment: the `as` name should be same as the one we specified no router or it can be different?